# Set UIButton Image with SVG file

Tags: ios, objective-c, svg, uibutton

I'm trying to set the Image of my UIBUtton with a SVG file...the click on the button works fine but it appears invisible. I'm trying to use PocketSVG: https://github.com/arielelkin/PocketSVG

There's what I'm trying:

```
CGPathRef myPath = [PocketSVG pathFromSVGFileNamed:@"icon_convidar.svg"];

        //2: To display it on screen, you can create a CAShapeLayer
        //and set myPath as its path property:
        CAShapeLayer *myShapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        myShapeLayer.path = myPath;


        //3: Fiddle with it using CAShapeLayer's properties:
        myShapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor greenColor] CGColor];
        myShapeLayer.lineWidth = 4;
        myShapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor greenColor] CGColor];

        //4: Display it!
    [self.btnConvidar.layer addSublayer:myShapeLayer];
```

Answer (score 0):

I only rewrite the line:

```
CGPathRef myPath = [PocketSVG pathFromSVGFileNamed:@"icon_convidar.svg"];
```

with the following line:

```
CGPathRef myPath = [PocketSVG pathFromSVGFileNamed:@"icon_convidar"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use SVG because iOS has no support for XML or SVG. PDF however will work. This is the best tutorial I have found on the subject: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/xcode-9-vector-images/